# How to split a HashMap in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` with size 14. I need to split the map so that I can get 14 maps of 1 size.
I've tried the following code, but the split is not working: the size after the split is still 14.

```
from("direct:receive-the-list")
    .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler())
    .bean(new ListToMapTransformer()) // aggregate list of strings into a Map of strings based on some prefix
    .log("Size of the body BEFORE SPLIT: ${body.size}");    
    .split(body())
    .log("Size of the body AFTER SPLIT: ${body.size}");
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like maybe you just want iterate on the map entries:

```java
.split(simple("${body.entrySet()}"))
    .log("${body.key}") // key is a String
    .log("${body.value}") // value is List<String>
```

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Ross. Actually, I need to split the map into multiple maps. 
eg. 
I have a map: 
"key1": ["value1", "value2"],
"key2": ["value3", "value4"],
"key3": ["value5", "value6"]
and I need to get the following:
map1 - "key1": ["value1", "value2"]
map2 - "key2": ["value3", "value"]
map3 - "key3": ["value5", "value6"]

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand your question bu I think this code examples solves your problem . split behaviour in Map is Map.Entry .  and this returns Node.class and you can get this value with .value

```
        from("timer:test?repeatCount=1")
            .process(e -> {
                Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name", List.of("name", "name1","namo"));
                map.put("surname", List.of("surname"));
                map.put("age", List.of("age", "age1"));
                e.getIn().setBody(map);
            })
            .split(body())
            .setBody(simple("${body.value}"))
            .log("${body.class} ${body.size} ${body}");
```

output

```
:class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 1 surname
:class java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN 3 name,name1,namo
:class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 2 age,age1
```

or more complicated example. u can split every list field to a body

```
from("timer:test?repeatCount=1")
        .log("its works")
        .process(e -> {
            Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name", List.of("name", "name1"));
            map.put("surname", List.of("surname", "surname1"));
            map.put("age", List.of("age", "age1"));
            e.getIn().setBody(map);
        })
        .split(body(), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
        .setBody(simple("${body.value}"))
        .split(body(), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
        .log("${body}");
```

Comment: Hi, @eray_p1 sorry I wasn't clear enough. If I have a map with 3 values e.g.
            map.put("name", List.of("name", "name1"));
            map.put("surname", List.of("surname", "surname1"));
            map.put("age", List.of("age", "age1"));

I need to get three separate maps:
map1: {"name": ["name", "name1"]}
map2: {"surname": ["surname"]}
map3: {"age"}: ["age", "age1"].
Do you maybe have an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Camel split EIP does not support maps. You can define your custom splitter bean if you want to iterate over the map, like shown here:
[can the Splitter EIP split a HashMap or does it have to be a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810028/can-the-splitter-eip-split-a-hashmap-or-does-it-have-to-be-a-list)